# Visual Basic 6 Command included on String Table

Tags: vb6, embedded-resource, resource-files

Here is the situation, I have this string table, in a `.res` file and I have some strings loaded into one of the forms, say Form1. On a form on I want to popup a message box with a message loaded from the string table using `LoadResString(1234)`.

Is it possible that when Resource ID 1234 contains `"This is testing vbNewline This is a new line!."` that string will be loaded using the said function onto the message box (popup box)?
I've tested it: It will also print out the `"vbNewline"` command and NOT parse it. Is there any other way to parse the said string making this kind of message ?

> This is testing
>   This is new line!.

I wanted that kind of message to appear.

Comment: is it possible for resource id 1234 to contain: "This is testing " & vbnewline & " This is a newline!." ?

Comment: vbNewline will be parsed as string resulting into "this is testing _ vbNewline _ this is new line!." something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to put a VB constant in a String expression so it is treating it like text, you can try using the [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bt3szac5%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) Function ( I realize this is a .Net link but the signature is the same as the VB6 method) to remove your string and substitute the correct value something like this should work:

```
MsgBox (Replace(LoadResString(1234), "vbNewLine", vbNewLine))
```

or create a function like this:

```
Public Function ParseNewLine(value As String) As String
    ParseNewLine = Replace(value, "vbNewLine", vbNewLine)
End Function
```

and call it like this:

```
MsgBox (ParseNewLine(LoadResString(1234)))
```

Comment: tried this and this works, any chance of having any other way besides this? like C or java like doing \n on string table?

Comment: @lemoncodes Mark Bertenshaw's answer is correct, if you use the Control Enter key combination where you want your newline.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you embed the newline sequence into the RES file. If you are using the Resource Add-In, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert these characters.

In visual Studio's resource editor and a raw resource script, you can use `\n`.

Comment: hmmm i've tried adding this onto the string table "this is testing \n this is new line" result was "this is testing (some garbage char)n this is new line"

Comment: "\n" only works in the Visual Studio IDE. As I mentioned above, you want to use Ctrl + Enter for the VB6 IDE.